# Are Lufthansa rebooking fees per leg, per flight, or per ticket?

Tags: tickets, airlines, fees-and-charges, lufthansa

I have a 2-leg flight (through Frankfurt) booked with Lufthansa, return ticket (Economy Basic). The travel agent has informed me that the rebooking fee is 70 EUR.

Is this per leg, or per flight, or per ticket? For example, if I want to change both the departure and return dates, do I pay 70, or 2x70 (or is it, perhaps, 4x70 - they charge extra baggage per leg, and for both ways)

Comment: I would say it is per fare, i.e. per ticket. You might have a outbound ticket that is re-bookable for free, and an inbound ticket which is not. Anyhow best thing to do is: ask the travel agent/airline.

Answer (score 4):

Checked with the travel agent, and the fee is per ticket - so, 70 EUR even if I change both the outbound and return dates.

Comment: Do you mean per booking, then? Per ticket to me means you would have to pay once per ticket, i.e. twice in case you change *both* outbound and inbound flights.

Comment: A single booking is a single ticket.  The OP's booking consists of 1 ticket (X to Y return), 2 legs (X to Y, Y to X) and 4 flights (X-FRA, FRA-Y, Y-FRA, FRA-X).

Comment: @jpatokal I always assumed that you had one ticket per leg, simply because the Reservation Code remains the same across tickets, whilst the electronic ticket number changes (usually in an incremental fashion).

Comment: @JoErNanO Not really, all my _return tickets_ by Czech Airlines have got one amadeus (6-character) code and one ticket (3+10-digit) number.